# How to use Phalanger to compile php into standalone console app?

Tags: php, compilation, phalanger

I would like to make a stand alone, completly independent command line application of my php script. I found Phalanger and tried to compile it using the phpc file... it did create an exe and it worked great on my computer, but when i try to use it on other computers it gives the error: Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly Versdion=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutrak... System cannot find the file specified. At .Run(String[] )

Am i doing something wrong? or do i need to install something to the computer before using my compiled application?  i would like to make a completly independent console app, just like in C# or vb.net... thanks

Update: The computer i compiled it and it worked on is a Windows 8 x64 build 9200, the non working computer is windows 7 ultimate x64

Comment: What version of Windows are your working and non-working computers using?

Comment: Please attach full stack trace, posible, you not insert in build required libs.

Comment: How can i get the stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

PHP application compiled with Phalanger needs Phalanger runtime (PhpNetCore.dll and PhpNetClasslibrary.dll). Deploy your app together with these (and optionally other PhpNet*.dll assemblies) or install Phalanger on target machine.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason might be that the dll is compiled on your machine, and therefore needs to be unblocked on the other machines. Check this by right clicking the dll on the other machine, and press the unblock button in the properties window if it is blocked.